# Implementing Single Sign On in SharePoint 2013 On-Premise Multi-Tenant environment using OAuth with other websites or systems

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, multi-tenancy, single-sign-on, oauth

Can anyone please provide a detailed walk through with steps for implementing Single Sign On in SharePoint 2013 On-Premise Multi-Tenant environment using OAuth with other websites or systems?

Comment: I am looking for the same  requirement.Can anyone pls help by providing the approaches/steps to follow to implement the SSO in SP 2013 on-premises.

Comment: Ditto. Since SharePoint consumes the SAML 1.1 token and stores only a FedAuth cookie, how does a non-SharePoint web application accept that FedAuth cookie to trust the SharePoint authentication for the other site? -John